# NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException when a parent and child class are components

Tags: java, spring

I have a parent class

```
package com.org.pages.home;

@Component
public class HomePage extends BasePage {

}
```

I have a sub-class

```
package com.org.pages.home;

@Component
public class WebHomePage extends HomePage {

}
```

When I try to get an instance of HomePage in the following manner:

```
T page = applicationContext.getBean(registeredClass);
//Here registeredClass is of the type Class<T> and contains reference to com.org.pages.home.HomePage
```

It throws an exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.org.pages.home.HomePage' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: homePage,webHomePage
```

**Questions**
1. Why am I seeing this exception when I am clearly passing the class that I want to get a bean for?
2. How can I fix this? Please note that I cannot autowire these classes anywhere as there are around 40 of them, which is why I am instantiating them using

```
applicationContext.getBean();
```

Thanks for any help/suggestion!

Comment: `WebHomePage` is a `HomePage` when getting `HomePage` it doesn't know which instance you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two beans that are `HomePage` instances : `homePage` and `webHomePage`.
So Spring doesn't know which `homePage` instance you want as you invoke `getBean(Class clazz)` in this way `ApplicationContext.getBean(HomePage.class)`.

Note that if you  invoke `ApplicationContext.getBean(WebHomePage.class)`, it would work as you have a single instance of `WebHomePage`.

As alternative with the programmatic way to retrieve the bean, you can use `ApplicationContext.getBean(String name)`  by passing the bean name such as :

`HomePage homePage = ApplicationContext.getBean("homePage")`

Or :

`HomePage homePage = ApplicationContext.getBean("webHomePage")`

> Please note that I cannot autowire these classes
>   anywhere as there are around 40 of them, which is why I am
>   instantiating them using

I don't really get why you could not use `@@utowired`.   You should autowire the beans a the place where you need them.
Retrieving 40 beans in one shot will give too much responsibility to your method and to your class.

Comment: will ApplicationContext.getBean(String name) work if I pass name of the parent class bean? I have situations where I *have* to get an instance of parent class.

Comment: Try it but I don't see why it will not work. Here you have two beans : `homePage` and  `webHomePage`. You should be able to retrieve any of them by specifying them. I updated with an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot @davidxxx. providing names worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

By Default, Spring framework automatically searches for matching bean. In case you have more than one bean for the same class(which includes the child classes) then you have to use

```
@Qualifier("beanName")
```

for matching by bean Name.

In your case, You can do the following:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("homePage")
public class HomePage extends BasePage {
}
```

and

```
@Component
@Qualifier("webHomePage")
public class WebHomePage extends HomePage {

}
```

Now you can use the following to get the `HomePage` bean:

```
HomePage page = (HomePage)applicationContext.getBean("homePage");
```